# Normalize Json with Pandas with missing key as NAN or null

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to Normalize Json

```
{
...
"scoring":[
  {
    "id": "9e97e6fa-8fdb-4452-b930-d5c0b1ae4a6a",
    "full_name": "Tom Washington",
    "first_name": "Tom",
    "last_name": "Washington",
    "number": "49",
    "assignment": "Head Official",
    "experience": "27"
  },
  {
    "id": "c3f40018-e566-49d5-ad2a-6b7a2af0dfcc",
    "full_name": "J.T. Orr",
    "first_name": "J.T.",
    "last_name": "Orr",
    "number": "72"
  },
  {
    "id": "4362601e-767f-4b28-8b1a-9eb6606f2e36",
    "full_name": "Rodney Mott",
    "first_name": "Rodney",
    "last_name": "Mott",
    "number": "71",
    "assignment": "Official",
    "experience": "21"
  }
]
...
}
```

I am loading json from the URL

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize #package for flattening json in pandas df
import urllib.request,json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time

def fetchMatchDetails(url,csvPath):
 #url='https://api.sportradar.us/nba/xxxx'
     with urllib.request.urlopen(url)as url:
         d = json.loads(url.read().decode())



     gamesDf = json_normalize(d['scoring'])
     newDf=gamesDf[['id','full_name','first_name','last_name','number','assignment','experience']]
```

but as sometimes few of the columns gets missing among say last_name or number in that case it shows as **key_error** in Python

How can I have a nan or null value for the key not present.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correct, your code is already working well. I've tried it and it returned NaN for the keys which are missing. What is the problem exactly?

```
        full_name first_name   last_name number     assignment experience
0  Tom Washington        Tom  Washington     49  Head Official         27
1        J.T. Orr       J.T.         Orr     72            NaN        NaN
2     Rodney Mott     Rodney        Mott     71       Official         21
```

Comment: the problem occurs when another json another json comes as I am reading from url and it only has keys say id, full_name and number now upon doing the json_normalize(d['scoring']) , the schema is changed and newDf=gamesDf[['id','full_name','first_name','last_name','number','assignment','experience']] fails